# How to pronounce the name Géminard?

Tags: prononciation

The 'e' in Géminard has an accent over it, but I am not sure how to type that.

Comment: For you to correct (just pick and choose the one that fits): éèê

Comment: An acute accent (*é*) is more than likely used so I corrected it. Feel free to change it copy/pasting Feelew comment should this proper name is written otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The pronunciation of *Géminard* is regular, i.e. the way it is written creates no uncertainty for a native speaker.

The most common one in France would be /ʒeminaʁ/, something like "zhaymeenahr".

There are however a lot of possible variations depending on the speaker but they shouldn't not prevent cross-comprehension. For example *é* might be open /ɛ/ and even perhaps a diphthong, *a* might be an /ɑ/ and there are possible variants for *r* like /R/ or /χ/ or even not pronounced at all. The stable parts are *min* and the fact the ending *d* is never pronounced.

*Géminard* etymology is possibly from the Latin *gemini* (twin) which gave both *jumeau*  and *gémeau* in French.

Comment: In Quebec, A before R in the last syllable of a word is likely to be pronounced /ɑ/ (a few exceptions do exist, like _guitare_ or sometimes _marre_, but even these are not universally pronounced /a/). I agree that France is to some extent a reference in the language, but if one happens to travel in Quebec, /ʒeminɑʁ/ would become the most likely pronounciation encountered.

Comment: @Feelew You are right. Answer updated to take variations into account.